# Special Characters in XML Attribute and ColdFusion

Tags: xml, coldfusion, coldfusion-8, xml-nil

I need to create an XML Document with an element that requires the attribute `i:nil=true`. I've tried `<cfset StructInsert(mydoc.employee.name.XmlAttributes, "i:nil", "true")>`, but it returns the error *The right hand side of the assignment is not of type XML Node*. What I would like is this: `<name i:nil="true"/>`.

The XML is used to call a .NET web service, and the DTD specifies that `i:nil="true"` is the way to indicate a field is should be `null` in the database.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just set it.  Don't use `structInsert`. Example:

`mydoc.employee.name.XmlAttributes["i:nil"] = true;`